# device plugged-in / unplugged when turning on TV monitor

Tags: hdmi

I have an [eGlobal Mini-PC](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Fanless-i5-Mini-PC-Windows-Barebone-PC-Broadwell-Intell-Core-i5-5200U-2-7GHz-4K-HTPC/32366202925.html) which includes an Intel HD5500 graphics, connected via HDMI to a [LG 42LD460 TV](http://www.lg.com/au/tvs/lg-42LD460-lcd-tv). It generally works well, but:

- The PC is always-on, and turns off the TV after a timeout. When I turn the TV back on, the PC make a "device connected" and then a "device disconnected" sound.
- When I switch the TV to another HDMI input, the PC continuously makes "device connected" / "device disconnected" sounds through its speaker (connected to speaker port, not through HDMI). I have to mute the PC to avoid the sounds.
- The TV shows up as `Generic PnP monitor` in device manager. Previous PC showed it as "LG TV".
- [Entech MonInfo](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/moninfo.shtm) shows `Model name: LG TV`, so the ID signal does reach the PC. It also shows `Windows description: Generic PnP Monitor`.

This TV didn't have this issue with my previous PC, which had an AMD Radeon HD4650, also connected via HDMI.

Questions:

1. How can I determine what device is being connected/disconnected? I looked around in event viewer, but didn't find anything.
2. How can I avoid these sounds?

**Update:** I got a supposed BIOS update from eGlobal. But it was the exact same version I already had - GBDW 1.08, 8/29/2015 - and of course didn't change anything.

Comment: Epilogue: I now used the HDMI for sound as well, connecting the speakers to the TV's headphones output. So if the computer makes any sounds while the TV is switched away, I can't hear them.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI cables can send extra digital information to and from the tv to allow interaction between devices without using an extra cable. This new feature does not work on all HDMI cables but does work on new ones.
Your PC clearly recognizes the TV as a device even thought you may or may not be able to interact with it. It plays the disconnected sound because the cable can't send extra data or interact-able information.

If you use your PC with your TV on a regular basis, the best and simplest option would be to turn on your TV before your PC.

I hope this helped and although I don't know how to turn off connected sounds for individual devices, you can visit system sounds to turn it off altogether if you want. System devices can be found by searching it in the start menu or in control panel.

Comment: Thanks. I keep my PC always-on, so I can't turn on the TV before it... I'll update the original question with that.